# Can I use 'res' object in koa?

Tags: node.js, express, koa

I am pretty new to koa. My old code is in express, like:

```
//GET
exports.readMessages = function(req, res){
  var result;
  ...
  res.json({
    result: result
  });
};

//GET
exports.preAddMessage = function(req, res){
  var valueA;
  var valueB;
  ...
  res.json({
    valueA: valueA,
    valueB: valueB
  });
};

// POST
exports.addMessage = function (req, res) {
  data.messages.push(req.body);
  ...
  res.json(resultValue);

};
```

And I want to change it to code in koa, like:

```
//GET
exports.readMessages = function* () {
  ...
};
//GET
exports.preAddMessage = function* () {
  ...
};
//POST
exports.addMessage = function* () {
  ...
};
```

How to do it? *The question may seem silly, but it matters to me, thanks!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//GET
exports.readMessages = function* () {
  this.body = {result: result};
};
//GET
exports.preAddMessage = function* () {
  this.body = {
    valueA: valueA,
    valueB: valueB
  };
};
//POST
exports.addMessage = function* () {
  data.messages.push(this.request.body);  // you might need a body parser middleware if the request is json
  this.body = resultValue;
};
```